# Why does my output go faulty if i decide to input (1 2) while its asking for the x but works fine if i input(12)

Tags: c++

So for my code, it ask's the user to input a number for x but i happened to fat fingered it and i typed in (1 2) with a space between 1 and 2 and my code directly went to outputting my x and y even thought it didn't ask for y coordinates yet.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double x, y;
    cout << "Enter x coordinate: ";
    cin >> x;
    while (!cin.good() ) {
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Enter your x coordinate";
        cin >> x;
    }
    cout << "Enter y coordinate: ";
    cin >> y;
    while(!cin.good()){
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        cout << "Enter your y coordinate";
        cin >> y;
    }
    cout << "You x coordinate is at: " << x << ", Your y coordinate is at: " << y ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The stream extract operator `>>` reads *space delimited* input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `cin` you get input eather by entering the data and pressing enter or by seperting by spaces, so:

```
cin >> var;
cin >> var2;
```

can get input **eather** by entering var1's data and pressing enter and then entering var2's data and pressing enter **or** by entering data for both var1 and var2 seperated by spaces and if the data is valid it would accept it.

notice that when the data it `!cin.good()` it would start the `cin` again

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `1 2` into the stream. `cin >> x;` reads and removes the `1`. The `2` stays in the stream. `cin` only blocks if the stream is empty.